# What's wrong with my JDBC sql statement

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc, client-server

I'm writing a java socket app that allows a client to communicate with a server, one of the other requirements is that it also needs to initialize JDBC. I believe I have wrote my JDBC connection method correctly, and my insert statement has worked like this on similar projects. It might be a simple mistake as i'm not using an IDE, can someone tell me what is wrong with my SQL statement? All the info is right, but it won't compile.

Error:

```
C:\Users\imallin\My Documents> javac provider.java
Provider.java:88 ';' expected 
String sql = "Insert INTO 'users' ('ID', 'firstName') VALUES ("123","123")";
```

Comment: I removed the big code block, as it's not relevant at all.

Comment: At which point? I already have a ; at the end of the statement

Comment: Thanks, would you have any idea why i'm getting an error: com.mysql.jdbc.driver ? I have the jdbc jar in my classpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you need to escape the double quotes that are in your string. This is because when the compiler see's another `"` it thinks it is the end of the String definition and exepcts a semi-colon.

```
String sql = "Insert INTO 'users' ('ID', 'firstName') VALUES (\"123\",\"123\")";
```

Now that the Java compiler is happy, you will have SQL-related issues.

In general with SQL, you will want to use single quotes to represent a string. It appears MySQL specifically allows double quotes, but only when the [SQL QUOTES ANSI mode is not set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html). So it is best to use single quotes to represent strings here.

Here is what you probably want, assuming that the `ID` column is an  integer, and that the `firstName` column is a string/varchar.

```
String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName) VALUES (123,'123')";
```

Comment: The double quotes are simply wrong. Your second version is better, but all those other single quotes need to come out. And yes, quotes shouldn't be used around integers, but it looks like at least the `firstName` column isn't an integer column, so that data may just be for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks, would you have any idea why i'm getting an error: com.mysql.jdbc.driver ? I have the jdbc jar in my classpath

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, I understand. I am trying to work my answer to solve the immediate problem.

Comment: @user1080390, It's probably best to ask another question with more details pertaining to that different error. That is, if searching comes up with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

To slightly differ from the other answers that have been posted, you need to *not use* double quotes in your SQL. The single quotes you've used are all in the wrong places, and the double quotes are simply not allowed. Your statement should look like

```
String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName) VALUES ('123','123')";
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't escaped the double quotes in your SQL statement. Java sees your string as finishing before the first 123.

Comment: No,the double quotes aren't legal in the first place.

Comment: That depends on your RDBMS though. The quote issue was why the questioner was getting a compile error.

Comment: Yes that's why it wasn't *compiling*, but fixing it to be a failing query isn't that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
String sql = "Insert INTO 'users' ('ID', 'firstName') VALUES ("123","123")";
```

The double quoted string ends after `VALUES (`, and is immediately followed by a numeric token. That's illegal in Java. The immediate fix is to add backslashes:

```
String sql = "Insert INTO 'users' ('ID', 'firstName') VALUES (\"123\",\"123\")";
```

Though this would also work (assuming it's talking about integers, not strings):

```
String sql = "Insert INTO 'users' ('ID', 'firstName') VALUES (" + 123 + "," + 123 + ")";
```

More generally though, what's wrong with it is that you're doing an INSERT without using parameterization. This is virtually always the wrong thing in real code! JDBC has good support for parameterized queries, which you *should* use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes instead.

> "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName) VALUES ('123','123')";